# Finding unique and duplicate recored in array

Tags: php

> Suppose there is array(1,2,2,3,4,4,5)
>   I want print in this format
>   A-1
>   B-2
>   B-2
>   A-3
>   B-4
>   B-4
>   A-5

Comment: There are two logics which fits, one, %3 and two, the number is even or odd. What an ambiguity!!!!

Comment: Would you like to show what you have tried so far, although people have answered - you are expected to do some work yourself before asking.  SO isn't intended to be a free coding service.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be an iterative approach which in which we iterate over your input array, keeping track of whether the current value differs from the previous value.  If it does differ, then we switch the letter prefix from `A` to `B`, or vice-versa.

```
$array = array(1,2,2,3,4,4,5);
$output = array();
$flag = true;
$last_item = NULL;

foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item != $last_item && $last_item != NULL) {
        $flag = !$flag;
    }
    $prefix = $flag ? "A" : "B";
    array_push($output, $prefix."-".$item);
    $last_item = $item;
}
print_r($array);
print_r($output);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A-1
    [1] => B-2
    [2] => B-2
    [3] => A-3
    [4] => B-4
    [5] => B-4
    [6] => A-5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1.**

If it is based on Even/Odd, You can use `foreach`

```
foreach($a as $v){
 echo ($v % 2) ? 'A-'.$v : 'B-'.$v;echo ' ';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/XUafK

**Solution 2.**

Another way, if the same value repetations. You can use `array_count_values`

```
$a = array(1,2,2,3,4,4,5);
$b = array_count_values($a);
foreach($a as $v){
 echo ($b[$v] > 1) ? 'B-'.$v : 'A-'.$v;
 echo '<br/>';
}
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/hopM8

Comment: your solution assumes duplicates will only fall on even numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$arrayst = array(1,2,2,3,4,4,5);
foreach ( $arrayst as $number) {
    if ($number % 2) {
        echo "A-".$number." ";
    }else{
        echo "B-".$number." ";
    }
}
```